# CSS Align text vertically middle/center

Tags: css

I know it sounds pretty simple but it's not working for me. What am I doing wrong ?

```
.popuphdr {
      background-color:#00477f;
      height:30px;
      width:100%;
      margin:0px;
      color: #ffffff;
      vertical-align:middle;
}


<div class="popuphdr">
        <div>WARNING - Read carefully before proceeding</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried giving the outside div a height and then setting the `vertical-align` to the div inside?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ykLv2/1/  Block elements don't work like that.  You can make inline elements vertically center.  Here is the method I use to center a single line of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align: middle` does not apply to div elements (will not have the affect you are looking for)

See http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ for possible solutions, there are a few ways you can go about doing what you want to accomplish.

--

Taken from that page here is the css as simple solution:

```
.popuphdr {
    display: table;
    /* Your other CSS HERE as well, minus vertial-align */
 }

.popuphdr div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And here is an expanded jsfiddle with your js and adding text-align center as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/BqgVM/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of the Absolute centering (also pointed out in the link posted by crowebird). It works well and it is simple.

[More details here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

HTML

```
    <div class="popuphdr">
        <div>WARNING - Read carefully before proceeding</div>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.popuphdr {
    background-color:#00477f;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

[And a working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Andy94/5Q56R/)

Comment: Did not work for me. Change the height to 100px and see it in Fiddle.

Comment: It seems still fine to me, even after the change you asked for. http://jsfiddle.net/Andy94/5Q56R/1/

Comment: Really. I want it aligned vertically in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

```
.popuphdr{
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;

    background-color:#00477f;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

CSS Flexbox is amazing. Here are a couple links to learn more about it:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/